# Reverse and compare String

Tags: java, string, compare

I have started to learn java and I've run into some trouble. Just wondering why my compare string function is not working and always returning true;

The purpose of the program is to take an input of a string, reverse the string and see if the string is the same as the original input (palindrome).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class palinedromeString {


    private static Scanner keyboard;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a Palindrome");
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = keyboard.next();
        String original = input;

        System.out.println("You entered: " + original);
        System.out.println("Your String reversed is:" + " " + stringReverse(input));
        System.out.println(checkString(input, original));
    }

    public static String stringReverse(String a) {
        String result = "";

        for(int i = a.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
            result = result + a.charAt(i);
        }


        return result;
    }

    public static boolean checkString(String a, String b){

        if(b.equals(a)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
        return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: fyi `String reversed = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();` and `boolean  checkString(a, b) { return a.equals(b); }`

Answer (score 1):

`stringReverse` returns the reversed `String` (it doesn't operate in place). Update `input` and your code should work as expected. Something like,

```
input = stringReverse(input);
System.out.println("Your String reversed is:" + " " + input);
```

Also, `checkString` is equivalent to

```
return b.equals(a);
```

Comment: Ahh thankyou. So essentially I wasn't updating input with the newly reversed string. And it  was comparing the first input(not reverse) with the input again (original) always returning true.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing **input and original** to the checkString() method. those two  hold the same values. It's obvious you get true always.

```
checkString(stringReverse(input), original);
```

You have to use the above instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have different options.

1. Assign the

   stringReverse(input)

to a variable like

```
input=stringReverse(input);
```

before checking

2. Imesha Sudasingha's answer.

The thing is you are reversing the string into a different variable and it doesnot get reflected in the String you pass unless you explicitly assign it.

Answer (score 0):

Here in `checkString(input, original)` method, both the parameter has same value, Hence it always returns true.
You have to pass original and reversed string like this:

```
String reversedStr = stringReverse(input);
checkString(reversedStr , original);
```